# Is there any API to get Dropbox token using username and password?

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

I am trying to get an access token using my dropbox username and password.

I don't want to go and generate it from there site, as mentioned in there help documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Dropbox API apps should use the OAuth app authorization flow to get an access token for the user, so that the app doesn't have to directly handle the user's credentials. You can find more information on this process here:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/oauthguide

The method of generating it on the [App Console](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps) that you mentioned only works for the owner of the app, but the OAuth app authorization flow can be used for any account.

Note that while this does require manual user intervention, it generally only needs to be done once per user. Once the app has an access token for a user, it can store and re-use the token for future API calls without further manual user intervention.

Dropbox API access tokens don't expire by themselves, though they can be manually revoked by the user.

Comment: Thanks for info Greg